# App crashes on selecting history stack item

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios14

I am in the Notification Detail screen when I long press on the back button to see History Stack. Main Screen is the root view controller. All the other screens are shown using pushViewController. The issue is for all versions above ios 14

My screen hierarchy is as below:

```
Main Screen (UINavigationController)
    |
    V
User Screen (UIViewController)
    |
    V
Notifications Screen (UIViewController)
    |
    V
Notifications Detail Screen (UIViewController)
```

When I try to open the User Screen by selecting the screen from History Stack (long press on the back button), it crashes the app saying:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UINavigationController _setViewControllers:transition:animated:operation:], UINavigationController.m:1257
main : *** an exception [UINavigationControllers are not allowed in a navigation controller!
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8004288ab __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff80004dba3 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00007ff800b870cc _userInfoForFileAndLine + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x000000010c5c1813 __76-[UINavigationController _setViewControllers:transition:animated:operation:]_block_invoke + 255
```

Comment: Please confirm that you are in the Notification  Detail Screen when you try to go back to the User Screen. Is User Screen the root view controller of Main Screen? Were all screens displayed using `pushViewController`? The error seems to indicate there is more than one navigation controller involved. Please edit your question with more details. Also, does the problem only appear under iOS 14 or does it fail under iOS 16?

Comment: Does the issue happen with other combinations or only when trying to go from Notifications Detail screen to User screen? I just checked in one of my apps and I have no problems going back using the long press on the back button. Maybe it would help if you posted some relevant code showing the initial creation of the main nav controller and its root view controller plus the calls for each view controller being pushed. Please confirm there are no other nav controllers involved other than the main root nav controller. Is this on an iPhone or iPad?

Comment: Doesn’t happen with other items in the same screen but happens with other screens with the same hierarchy.

Comment: Do you have custom code on the back actions?

Comment: No, there is no custom code on back action.

Comment: @RahulA. Your main screen should  be a UIViewController (not navigation controller) .